# Updating Perl date functions? Date::Datecalc.pm not found

Tags: perl

I'm migrating a Perl script to a new system and am running into problems.  I ran "pear install date" and installed the Date module but this script is expecting some subroutines that seem to no longer be available?

When I run the script I get:

```
Can't locate Date/DateCalc.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./script.pl line 23.
```

I'm using these two functions which seem to not be available on this new system.

```
use Date::DateCalc qw(day_of_week dates_difference);
```

Is there a new library I need to install or change the reference to these functions in order to access them?

Comment: `pear` is for PHP; you want `cpan Date::DateCalc` (or the equivalent for your system's package manager).

Comment: ...although apparently [Date::DateCalc isn't on CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=612357). If your script on the other machine is working, you may have to copy Date/DateCalc.pm over by hand. I'm retracting my duplicate vote, this is a special case.

Comment: doh.. sorry... my mistake with pear.. get those confused... so for Perl modules they have to be manually copied?  there is no automated installer for modules?

Comment: Is there another date library I can use that would have these two functions available?

Comment: The Perl equivalent of `pear` is `cpan`, which downloads and installs modules and handles dependencies automatically. You can also use your system's package manager, e.g. `yum`, `apt-get`. Unfortunately, the module Date::DateCalc isn't on CPAN; according to the link in my last comment, it's available on backpan. If you can, you should really switch to a module that's actually maintained, like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

Comment: Is DateTime the most widely used library of this type?   i mainly need to get the difference between two dates.

Comment: I found the library.  But it looks like it won't compile on my new system and is a perl front end for a c-based library.  Perhaps the work around is to find a new source to replace this function:  dates_difference($year,$month,$day,$cyear,$curmon,$cmday)

Answer (score 0):

Date::DateCalc isn't a Perl library that I recognise. It's not available on [CPAN](http://metacpan.org/), so I assume it's a library that is written in-house or something that your project has acquired from elsewhere. You'll need to find out where it came from and see if you reinstall it from there. It may be possible to copy it from the old server onto the new one - but that can sometimes be a tricky undertaking.

For several years, [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) have been included in the standard Perl library. Neither of them have the specific subroutines that you ask for, but it would be simple to write them both based on these modules.

If you tell us what the input and output of these subroutines are, then someone here might write them for you.